# JQMobile App with Touchpunch not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am trying to get a Worklight 6.2 app JQueryMobile 1.4 mobile app working which has draggable widgets.  I have included js from touchpunch http://touchpunch.furf.com/ , where I have a button that I am trying to make draggable

```
<script>$('#draggableButton').draggable();</script>
```

I was wondering if anyone had tried getting touchpunch working with Worklight/jqm or if they ended up taking some other approach to create a draggable widget.  Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: There is also a vanilla solution that is easy to use (all you need to do is add the script): https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me after:

1. adding missing jquery-ui.js
2. adding missing `class="ui-widget-content"` declaration on the `a href`
3. I also moved the `.draggle()` to `wlCommonInit()`

[Modified HelloDraggable sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oj72j8hf7rfy2w/HelloDraggable.zip).

Comment: Hi Idan,  I didn't see the property 'msie' of undefined message.   In the logcat, I see:  8-12 21:28:18.537: E/NONE(29312): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at (compiled_code):23
08-12 21:28:18.547: E/NONE(29312): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable' at (compiled_code):44
08-12 21:28:18.557: E/NONE(29312): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable' at (compiled_code):20
Thx!

Comment: Since I did not get this error, you should provide a demo project exhibiting it.

Comment: Hi Idan,  Many thanks.  The code can be found here: [link](https://github.com/jeffet/HelloDraggable).  My apologies in advance if I did something stupid.

Comment: Idan, Thank you!  You are a star.